# $.ajax - call does not work

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I don't know why below code does not work.
I use jQuery 1.7.1:

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
```

in my _Layout.

It shows `alert('hello');`, but when i use firebug it goes on:

```
RedirectToAction("MainIndex", "Home");
```

i think allthings is true.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#btn_submit').click(function () {
        alert('hello');

        $.ajax({

            url: 'Product/IsUserPeresent',
            cache: false,
            type: 'Get',
            success: function (result) {

                alert(result);
                @* var url = '@Url.Action("ncheckout", "Home")';
                $.post(url, {
                    name: result
                          });*@

            },
            error: function () {
                RedirectToAction("MainIndex", "Home");
           }
        });
    });
});

</script>

public ActionResult IsUserPeresent(){

    //var nam = User.Identity.Name;

    var nam = "alex";
    return Json(nam, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Comment: Look at the Net tab of FireBug. There you will see the AJAX request and can inspect the response returned by the server. What is it? 404? 500? Also use an Url helper instead of hardcoding the url to your controller action: `url: '@Url.Action("IsUserPeresent", "Product")'`.

Comment: it looks like you have a razor comment...

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
$('#btn_submit').click(function (event) {
  event.preventDefault();

    alert('hello');

    $.ajax({

        url: 'Product/IsUserPeresent',
        cache: false,
        type: 'Get',
        success: function (result) {

            alert(result);
            @* var url = '@Url.Action("ncheckout", "Home")';
            $.post(url, {
                name: result
                      });*@

        },
        error: function () {
            window.location = '@Url.Action("MainIndex", "Home")';
       }
    });
});
```